How can i retrieve Auth data in 404 pages in Laravel 11
The fix was simple in previous Laravel version, but now with the current files restructuring, it is not clear how to solve this anymore,
i want the Auth data to be shared even in 404 pages, i personally don't see why it's that valuable not to share auth data inside 404 pages.
in short, i'm looking to have the Auth::user() data sent even in 404 pages in Laravel 11.

Try using the Route::fallback method. Use a controller or a callback function to load your custom 404 page and in this way, you will have access to auth()->user().
Route::fallback(function () {
    return view('errors.404');
});

You can find more information on the official docs
